# Given a radius R, find the minimal number of circles to maximize the area where the circles' center belong to a set of points P

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, language-agnostic

> Given a list of points, P, and a radius R, find the minimum set of points P that maximizes the area. Where each point represents a circle centered at that point.
>
> For example, given the points (3,2), (7,3), (0,-1), (5,-1), (4,1), the point (4,1) is redundant as it doesn't offer any extra area that isn't already covered by the other points.
>
> [image]

Would some kind of backtracking solution work? Where we calculate the area of every possible combination? Ideally there's a solution that's more efficient because I'd like this to handle a large number of points.

Another example:
[image]

In this case, the answer is all points because each point contributes to the total area covered. The ones in the middle give a little bit of area highlighted in yellow.

Is there solution that can be generalized for any radius? That is, each point has their own radius.

Comment: Is this equivalent to identifying which circles are contained in the union of other circles?

Comment: Answers [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76712/determine-if-circle-is-covered-by-some-set-of-other-circles) might be of some help.

Comment: Don't you mean a set of circle centres {x,y,r}? My approach would be to calculate the area of the intersection of all other circles inside the ith circle. If it's the whole ith circle area you can exclude it. You can immediately exclude all circles with no intersection, so you might be left with a small number of circles to consider each time.

Comment: @CarySwoveland how would you efficiently determine the minimum set? Would I be bruteforcing every possible combination of circles?

Comment: @Spectacles4, sorry, but without doing research I can be of no help.

Comment: This isn't really a programming problem, but a geometry problem that is best asked over on the [math.se] site.

Comment: People, please stop close-voting every question you somehow don't like.  This is a good, clear, on-topic question and it already has 2 close votes.  @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I guess this means you.

Comment: It is *both* a programming problem and a geometry problem. It is on-topic on both sites.

Comment: The reason I say it's not really a programming question, given the _current post text_, is that there's no (flavour of) programming language  indicated, and different languages allow implementations of this in _vastly_ different ways, so as currently written, this is a maths question more than a programming question unless and until it's framed within the context of a (family of) programming language(s).

Comment: Algorithm questions can be language-agnostic, as this one is. I've added a [tag:language-agnostic] tag to make it explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are given **n** center points, you only need to consider at most **n<sup>2</sup>** "point of interest", including:

- The given circle centers; and
- The at most 2 circle intersection points for every pair of centers.

If a point of interest is not intersected by any circles (it must be a center point), then it represents a distinct enclosed area.  Find all the circles that contain it.

Otherwise, if a point if interest is intersected by **k** circles, then it is adjacent to at most **2k** enclosed areas.  For each of those areas, find all the circles that contain it.

All of the above can be done in O(n<sup>2</sup> log n) time.

Now you have a bunch of circle sets, each of which contains the set of circles that cover some area.  Assign an ID to each distinct circle set.

Then, for each circle center, construct the set of IDs for all the circle sets that its circle covers.

You have transformed your problem into a [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) -- your goal is to find the smallest number of center ID sets that cover all of the IDs.

As mentioned in the linked Wikipedia article, this is an NP-hard problem, but the instances you create are likely to be pretty easy.